# Wix: How to set a Feature State "This Feature Will Not be available"?

Tags: wix, state

I've assigned a task in which one sub feature among 4 should be displayed to the user in the state as "This Feature Will Not be available"

For instance, I have this feature set:

```
<Feature Id="Main" AllowAdvertise="no" ConfigurableDirectory="MYROOT" Description="Required components"   Display="expand" Level="1" Title="Main Feature" Absent="disallow">
        <ComponentRef Id ="Cmp22"/>

    <Feature Id="SubFeature_1" AllowAdvertise="no" Level="1"> 

    </Feature>
    <Feature Id="SubFeature_2" AllowAdvertise="no" Level="1"> 

    </Feature>
    <Feature Id="SubFeature_3" AllowAdvertise="no" Level="1"> 
            <!-- I want this feature to displayed as "This Feature Will Not be available" -->
    </Feature>

</Feature>
```

I've tried with different **Level** values.

Also, I used a VbScript custom action using **Session.FeatureRequestState** method, to change it at runtime, but can't get enough results.

Can someone please guide me about this?

Thanks and Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the level to a value higher than INSTALLLEVEL property value:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369536(VS.85).aspx

For example, if INSTALLLEVEL is 3, your feature level should be 4. To determine the INSTALLLEVEL value you can check the Property table in your MSI.

Comment: Cosmin,
Thanks a lot for some informative reply. 
I've opened the msi into Orca to see its property table and there is no INSTALLLEVEL there.

Comment: According to MSDN: "If no value is specified, the install level defaults to 1."

Comment: I achieved this using a vbscript custom action at runtime :).